# What is the value of RedHat Openshift Application Runtimes compared with just OpenShift Container Platform?

Tags: openshift, redhat-rhoar

What is the value of RedHat Openshift Application Runtimes? I'm trying to understand what is RedHat Openshift Application Runtimes (RHOAR) but I'm not able to find something that talks specifically about RHOAR assets, what I'm buying.

All I see is videos of developing demo applications that uses CI/CD features of OCP.

The idea I'm building is that RHOAR is an entitlement that gives me licenses and support for JBoss and in case I have issues with vert.x WildFly, Spring Boot or Tomcat I will be able to open an issue with RedHat. May be also access to a repository with pre-built images of these technologies?

I'm not able to find or understand what gets the customer buying RHOAR. As said I only find videos of developing sample apps, but I guess a customer would not pay just for samples/documentation.

The lines from redhat are: "A commercial offering based on open source that provides support , along with assets such as "boosters and missions"
Those boosters and missions is what I have understood are sample applications.
The concept left is "commercial offering based on open source that provides support", that is what I have supposed that is support for JBoss, vert.x, WildFly and Spring Boot and preconfigured container images. (I would say openshift build and runtime images)

Comment: When you buy RHOAR you are getting access to set of Red Hat developed container images written to deploy seamlessly to the OpenShift platform.